# Most natural way of remarking "That's annoying"?

Tags: oral

Just for something simple, like a restroom being out of soap or a splinter or spilt milk. What's a very common way of remarking casual frustration?

*C'est frustrant* didn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on how polite you want to be.

Vulgar options (and certainly the most natural for most people) would be "et merde" (literally "shit"), "fait chier" (no translation possible, literally "it's making me shit"), "chiotte" (vulgar word for "toilets"), "bordel" (literally, "brothel"), "putain" (literally, "whore")...

A bit more polite but still vulgar: "crotte" ("turd"), "punaise" / "purée" (the literal sense isn't helpful as these are euphemisms for "putain").

More polite (but these sound a bit stiff to my ears) would be "zut", "flûte" (literally, "flute"), "mince" (or "mince alors", literally it means "thin"), "bon sang" (literally "good blood"), "bon sang de bonsoir" ("good blood of good evening"), "nom de nom" (literally "name of a name"), "sapristi".

If you want to go into the "outdated" section (don't use these unless you're playing a character from the 18th century), you have "diantre", "sacrebleu", "ventrebleu", "ventre-saint-gris", "crévindiou" and similar.

Then you have the whole range of onomatopoeia. "Pfff", "ohh", "ohlala"...

Answer (score 1):

Najib has covered most bases.  Where I come from, it there are a few "polite" options:

> Zut !

meaning, "Bother!" or "Drat!"

Another option, that Najib didn't mention, is:

> Voyons donc !

Literally, it means "Let us then see!"  It would tend to more often be applied to a person who is not complying, so if you used it in this situation, it would tend to imply that you mildly upset with yourself (or someone else for distracting you so you spilled it or whatever).